# Maximum vote percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Assume a small town is holding elections, each citizen gets to vote as many times as they want, but their vote gets split the more times they vote.

My input is like below

Table: town_elections

```
Voter Vote
Jane Jane 
Howard Jane
John Howard
John Jane
Jane John
Sara Howard
```

Expectation:

```
Jane    Jane   0.33
Howard  Jane   0.33
John    Howard 0.5
John    Jane   0.33
Jane    John   1.0
Sara    Howard 0.5
```

Comment: Sorry iam not using sql server 2005 and i need splits based on vote share

Comment: I do not see how the expected results follow from the explanation.  Why is Jane/Jane 0.33 when Jane only voted twice?  Sara only voted once, why is her weighting 0.5?

Answer (score 2):

Try below query. For your desired result `cast to decimal` is used here

```
with MyCTE
as
(
select 
voter,
Vote,
count(*) over(PARTITION BY Vote order 
by Vote) as votecount
from town_elections
)
select Voter,Vote, cast((cast(100 as decimal(18,2))/cast(votecount as 
decimal(18,2)))/100.00 as decimal(18,2)) as percentage from MyCTE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply count the vote with `group by` and then divide each row based on the match with the count.

try the following:

```
;with cte as
(
   select vote, count(vote) cnt
   from yourtable t
   group by vote
)

select t.*, cast(1.0/cnt as numeric(5,2)) as share
from yourtable t
join cte on cte.vote = t.vote
```

You can also use self join to get the desired result.

please see the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=1de0433db8fa893b6407545f818486f7)**.